# Giving my members privet data!

Tags: plugins

I sell Services on my website, usually after people pay me and I confirm their payment I sent them the data that require for using my APP it's like username and password and list of servers that they can use.
I send them these info by e-mail, is it possible to build login area to make these info privet in their login area! or is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can do that. Have a dashboard build for each user using WordPres.

There are plugins which can atleast get you started:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-dashboard/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/client-dash/

Now create a template where you display your services as per the payments. Also make sure you have a login criteria added the template.